# Different Output Voltages from Same Source?

Tags: electronics, voltage

I'm wondering whether it is possible to wire multiple buck converters with different voltage requirements and amperage draws to the same power source (this idea is for controlling a radio-controlled boat). Going off other related questions this seems to be possible ([1](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/260312/are-there-limits-for-the-number-of-buck-converters-i-can-run-off-a-single-power), [2](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/481666/using-buck-converter-and-ldo-from-the-same-power-source)).

My background is in programming, not electronics, so the terminology is difficult for me to understand. I'm getting a grasp on voltage and amperage. My problem is always understanding how electricity can be "split" into different modules. In my understanding, this below would be a parallel circuit and that should be fine.

1. Are there any gotchas to consider with this type of circuit, or is this the totally normal way of doing things (eg. like wiring a house out of a breaker box)?
2. Is there a better way to do this?
3. This won't cause a short circuit, right?

[image: SLA battery powering different voltages diagram]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are there any gotchas to consider with this type of circuit, or is this the totally normal way of doing things (eg. like wiring a house out of a breaker box)?

That's a perfectly normal way of wiring it.

> Is there a better way to do this?

No, it's how I'd do it.

> This won't cause a short circuit, right?

Not intentionally, no. However it's always good to add a fuse or two to protect everything just in case anything untoward should happen. Especially where water is concerned.